# Errors when creating folders in virtualenv

Tags: python, directory, virtualenv

I have some troubles with creating folders in virtualenv. The directory is right. The folder is created but there are a lot of errors. Tried to reinstall Python, pip and Django. Nothing worked for me.

[image]

Comment: Please dont put link here, can you please paste it

Comment: It looks like there's a Unicode error because something is expecting a filepath as a string, but your unicode username means that your filepath is also unicode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that python2 by default uses the ascii encoding when opening files and when encoding file paths.
And your username contains non-ascii characters - so, it gives this error.

---

So, first off - I'd recommend you use python3 - python2 is old, python3 is going to be the next thing which will be supported. This will automatically fix this issue, as python3 uses unicode by default.

---

But if you want to continue with python2 ...

One possible method is changing this behaviour to use utf. Make `sitecustomize.py` and add:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('UTF8')
```

More info here - https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html

---

The easier method is simply dont do it in your HOME directory (i.e. make sure the path doesnt have your username)

Make a `C:\python_venv` and do it there.